# Decode the following message which was sent using mod m=7081 and exponent k=1789 (RSA)

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Decode the following message which was sent using mod $m = 7081$ and exponent $k=1789$ (RSA):
$$
5192 2604 4222
$$
I solved $\phi(7081)=6912$, and then solved the linear equation $1789u-6912v=1$ where $u=85$ and $v=22$.

But then, when I plugged this into  $5192^{85} \pmod{7081}$, successive squaring gave me $0$, which is clearly incorrect.

I got:
$$
85=2^0+2^2+2^4+2^6
$$
$$
5192^1=5192 \pmod{7081}\\
5192^2=6578 \pmod{7081}\\
5192^4=5174 \pmod{7081}\\
5192^8=0 \pmod{7081}
$$
I also got the other two numbers $(2604, 4222)$ raised to the $8$th power are congruent to $0$. Where did I go wrong in this problem?

Comment: What are you using to calculate this? $5192^8 \equiv 4096 \pmod {7081}$

Comment: I was using Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Specifically, your last step is wrong; $5192^4 \equiv 5174$, but then $5192^8 \equiv 5174^2 \not \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Joseph: Wolfram Alpha gives the correct answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5192^8+mod+7081

Comment: Try plugging this into Wolfram Alpha: 4222^(2^3) mod 7081 it gives the wrong answer. but thanks, I figured out the code.

Comment: @Joseph, I just plugged in exactly that and it gave the correct answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4222%5E%282%5E3%29+mod+7081

Comment: Better yet for entering into Wolfram Alpha: `PowerMod[4222, 2^3, 7081]`

Comment: @Zach: Bizarre. I clicked your link and it gave me 0. But anyway, I got the code. Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it right, in that $d=85$ is the decryption exponent, as $d$ and $e = 1789$ are inverses modulo $\phi(n) = \phi(7081) = 6912$. 
Entering `5192 ** 85 % 7081` in python, I get 1615, which seems like 2 letters (using A = 1, etc in a digraphic code).
Also the other 2 groups give 2823 and 1130, which seems to imply some extra characters besides just letters. Wolfram alpha agrees (entering `5192^85 mod 7081` etc.)

Just curious: what does this mean in your code?

Comment: It means Fermat. The code starts at A=11, B=12, etc.